# QGIS 3.10 atlas / composer, avoid missing text edge of map?

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

How to avoid missing texts near edge between map images?

I have vector topographic map which need to cut through map names.
When I create atlas project using Composer, those cutting text are missing from both maps. How to solve this problem?

I am using 3.10 version

[image: view from QGIS]
[image: Missing names in final version]

Comment: Are you showing two contiguous maps ? is there anything overlapping the text ?

Comment: How have you placed your labels?

Comment: If you're using the default label placement, the labels will be re-arranged for each separate map in the atlas. Try using data-defined placement, so that each label is always in the same place.